# Clean Firstname which has special characters and numbers

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have junk in my firstname field and i want to clean them . i am trying to see the names that are not valid(contains all special characters , numbers are invalid).

```
select firstname 
from table 
where firstname !~'[[:alpha:]]'
```

my query doesn't work in the right way.

Input values in the table looks like:

```
Firstname
---------
jack
1h7kk
$han
M.a
pac*^
___*(6&%
a
```

Output(should look like this )

```
Firstname
---------
1h7kk
$han
pac*^
___*(6&%
```

Your help is appreciated.

Thank You, Swathi.

Comment: Periods (.), apostrophes ('), and dashes (-) are all perfectly normal characters in both first and last names, even if they are somewhat rare. And don't forget about possible foreign names, especially Russian and Asian which have greatly different character sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to get all the invalid first names, use

```
select name
from t 
where name !~*'^[a-z]+$'
```

use `*`  for case insensitive matching.

To get valid names, use

```
select name
from t 
where name ~*'^[a-z]+$'
```

[**`SQL Fiddle`**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c3a35/4)

Edit: Per OP's comment, the firstname can also have `-` and `space` character which are valid.

```
select name
from t 
where name ~*'(^[a-z]+\.?\-?\s*?[a-z]+\.?$|^[a-z]+$)'
```

[**`SQL Fiddle with edit`**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c86c1/2)

Explanation:

- `^[a-z]+` starts with one or more characters in the range a-z (case insensitive)
- `\.` followed by an optional `.`
- `\-?` followed by an optional `-` character
- `\s?` followed by an optional space
- `[a-z]+` followed by one or more characters in the range a-z (case insensitive)
- `\.$` ends with an optional `.`

Comment: HI vkp, Thank you so much for your great respond. it worked for me .Appreciate your help!

Comment: Hi vkp , I am unable to filter if i have this in my column..these are invalid name. Please advice me
S-Test-wall
CJ23
william "Bill"
Return009
DBI42510-Test-Evoke
Martin Luther King
João

Comment: I tried this
drop table if exists t1;
create table t1 (Firstname varchar(100));
INSERT INTO t1
    (Firstname)
VALUES
    ('jack'),
    ('1h7kk'),
    ('$han'),
    ('M.a'),
    ('pac*^'),--
    ('___*(6&%'),
    ('a'),
    ('12lucassiva'),
    ('___---__--_-')
    ,('abdul kan sha')
    ,('-CINDY'),
    ('ReturnXX4')
    ,('RAPPgilead5F'),
    ('Sidro "Sid"'),
    ('João')

My query
select Firstname from t1
where firstname  !~*'(^[a-z]+\.?\-?\s*?[a-z]+\.?|^[a-z]+$)'

output:
1h7kk,$han,___*(6&%,12lucassiva,___---__--_-,-CINDY,ReturnXX4',RAPPgilead5F,Sidro "Sid",João

Comment: yes they are invalid and the query doesn't return them. see [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2a539/1)

Comment: Awesome. Thank You So much vkp:)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a cursor to loop through each entry in your table, then looping through each of those character by character, testing each one with `ISALPHA()` to see if any of the characters in the name is not an alphabetic character. Like so:

```
DECLARE AlphaCursor CURSOR
FOR SELECT firstname
FROM TABLE;

DECLARE @string varchar(15);

DECLARE @index int;
DECLARE @len int;
DECLARE @char char(1);

DECLARE @IsGood Boolean;

OPEN AlphaCursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM AlphaCursor INTO @string;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

@IsGood = TRUE;

SET @index = 1;
SET @len= LEN(@string);

WHILE @index<= @len
BEGIN
SET @char = SUBSTRING(@string, @index, 1)
IF NOT ISALPHA(@char) THEN
@IsGood = FALSE;
END;

SET @index= @index+ 1;
END;

IF NOT @IsGood THEN
PRINT @string;
END;

FETCH NEXT FROM AlphaCursor INTO @string;

END;
```